# How do I terminate this loop?

Tags: java

"Only one while loop should be used to determine all even and odd numbers between 50 and 100."

```
public class EvenOdd {

public static void main(String args[]) {

    int x = 50;
    int y = 50;
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;
    int n = 0;

    System.out.print("Even numbers between 50 and 100: ");
    while((i != x) || (j != y)) {
        n++;
        System.out.print(i + x + ", ");
        i += 2;
        if(i != x)
            continue;

        System.out.println("100");

        System.out.print("\nOdd numbers between 50 and 100: ");

        System.out.print((j+1) + y + ", ");
        j += 2;

        if(j != y)
            continue;

    }       
  }
}
```

The evens print fine but the odds continue on forever. This may be a dumb question, but I'm having the biggest brainfart right now, and I would really appreciate help on this.

Comment: Why do you use `continue` statement? I think you could avoid it.

Comment: The location of System.out.print("\nOdd numbers between 50 and 100: "); is wrong. It should be out of the while loop. This is the first. The second one is you can use two loops. It will be easier then this.

Comment: This question calls for using only one while loop, that's why I'm only using one. Also, wouldn't the System.out.print("\nOdd numbers between 50 and 100: "); just supposedly print after the infinite number of odd numbers? @CeylanB.

Comment: Well, I don't think that the odds are on forever. Once It reaches 50 on `i`, you count odds one time, but when you re-enter the `while` loop, it changes the `i` value, making it different from `x`, always falling to `continue`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply try this and let me know. It's based on your code, with just a few minor adjustments:

```
public class Teste4 {

public static void main(String args[]) {

    int x = 50;
    int y = 50;
    int i = 0;
    int j = 1;
    int n = 0;

    System.out.print("Even numbers between 50 and 100: ");
    while((i < x) || (j < y)) {
        if(i < x){
            System.out.print(i + x + ", ");
            i += 2;
            continue;
        }else if(i == x){
            System.out.println("100");
            i++;
        }

        if(j == 1){
            System.out.print("\nOdd numbers between 50 and 100: ");
        }

        System.out.print(j + y + ", ");
        j += 2;
    }       
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you should try this

```
    int even_counter = 50;
    int odd_counter=51;
    System.out.println("Even numbers between 50 and 100: ");
    while((even_counter < 100 ) || (odd_counter < 100)){
        if(even_counter < 100){
            System.out.print(even_counter+ " ");
            even_counter+=2;
            continue;
        }

        if(odd_counter < 100){
            if(odd_counter == 51){
                System.out.println("\nOdd numbers between 50 and 100: ");
            }
            System.out.print(odd_counter+ " ");
            odd_counter+=2;
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure this is an assignment but i'll add my 2 cents since it's solved. This one will give you an array.

```
final int EVEN = 0, ODD = 1;
int low = 50, high = 100, current = low;
int[][] numbers = new int[2][];
numbers[EVEN] = new int[((high - low) / 2) + ((high - low) % 2)];
numbers[ODD]  = new int[((high - low) / 2)];
while(current < high){
    numbers[current % 2][(current - low) / 2] = current++;
}
System.out.println("EVEN" + Arrays.toString(numbers[EVEN]));
System.out.println("ODD " + Arrays.toString(numbers[ODD]));
```

Answer (score -1):

Alternative approach ,

```
int current = 50 , end = 100 ;
String odd , even ;
while(current <= 100){

    if (current % 2 == 0)   
        even = even.concat ("," + current);
    else 
        odd = odd.concat("," + current);
    current++;
}

System.out.println("Even no are : " + even);     
System.out.println("Odd no are : " + odd);
```

I dont have a compiler now . I think this should be right :) .